# Keep cells from shifting up when hiding totals row VBA

Tags: excel, vba

A few months ago, I created a workbook in Excel 2010 for one of my co-workers to automate some reports.  To work within the constraints, I wound up with pivot tables to summarize the accounts and tables next to them to pull in the numbers.

I had run into a problem where VBA threw an error if I was switching to a report with fewer rows because I was removing table rows and the pivot table couldn't be modified.  I worked around it by hiding the totals row, resizing the table, and then showing the totals row again.

Today, I was showing my co-worker how to handle one of the "oops we forgot" updates she received and noticed the formatting was goofed up on one of the reports.  While trying to figure out what was going on, I finally realized that Excel was **deleting** the cells when it hid the totals and then shifting up the data below it.

If I need to, I can have the macro shift the affected cells back down, which I *think* will prevent the formatting from getting funky, but I'd prefer not to if there is another way.

I am hiding the totals row with

```
tbl.ShowTotals = false
```

where `tbl` is a ListObject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tbl.ShowTotals = Not tbl.ShowTotals
```

Comment: The problem isn't toggling it - the problem is the deletion/shifting of cells! I do actually pass a variable for whether to show or hide, although being next to the pivot tables also made it necessary to "cheat" showing them by filling in one of the cells with a formula because `tbl.showTotals = true` would throw an error.